# how to reduce number of tries left in java

Tags: java

```
        if(guess.equals(selection)){
            System.out.println("win");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(attemptsLeft <= 0){
            System.out.println("loose");
        }else  {
           attemptsLeft--;
           System.out.println("retry, tries left  " +" " + attemptsLeft);

        }
```

I want it for every wrong guess to decrease number of tries by 1. This code decreases it from 3 to 2 but not from 2 to 1. No matter how many mistakes its always gonna print "retry, tries left 2"

Comment: can you post the entire code block, specifically where `selection` and `attemptsLeft` are declared, you're going to have to use some sort of iteration to do this

Comment: can you give the whole block of code in your loop statement? You may be redeclaring your `attemptsLeft` to `3` per iteration

Comment: https://pastecode.xyz/view/daabd916

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable outside of the method block, cause the block will init a new variable (as 3) at every method call:

Declare it as a class field:

```
    int attempsLeft = 3;
    private void evaluateGuess() {
        //rest
```

This way the value will be kept between method calls inside the class.